# Where are the tags in ServiceStack that mark the releases

Tags: servicestack

I'm having issues with ServiceStack on MonoTouch and I want to build it myself. Unfortunately the latest code hits a bug in MonoTouch so I want to start from the known point of the latest release code.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/release/latest/MonoTouch

Currently marked as 3.85.

Normally I would look for a tag in the repo to work from but I couldn't find any. How do I get the source used to build 3.85?

Cheers,
Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Git project doesn't tag their releases, you would need to travel back to the commit logs to [see where v3.85 and the MonoTouch libs were added](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commits/master?page=20) to the project.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance as I'm relatively new to github and indeed to DVCS, but isn't ServiceStack.Text a seperate repo? Do I just take the date and time that the ServiceStack.Text.dll file was added to ServiceStack and use that to get the state of the SS.Text repo? Wouldn't it be better to use a tag in SS and SS.Text so that anyone can be more sure of building the release as it was intended?

Comment: SS.Text is a separate rep, SS.Common that has the clients is in the main repo. We don't use tags, we're a rapidly evolving project with nearly weekly releases, use the commit history to find the code at the point in time you're looking for.

Comment: Ok. I built SS.Text from just after it was set to 3.85 and modified the RegisterTypeForAot<T>() method to make a RegisterTypeForJsonAot<T>(). This was to try and address...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796704/calling-servicestack-text-jsconfig-registertypeforaott-with-monotouch-cause